# In NeDB is an array in a document better than multiple documents?

Tags: electron, nedb, nosql

I am making an electron app using NeDB as a database.
The document structure is as follows:

```
For a machine (<= 150 machines), I need to add a comment for the
machine regularly.
```

For such a scenario which document structure would be better

1. Make 1 document for the machine and push each entry
   to an array field in the document.

   ```
   {
    machine_no : string,  
    date: [Date],  
    comment: [string]  
   }
   ```
2. For each entry make a new document with the machine_no in it.

   ```
   {
    machine_no : string,  
    date: Date,  
    comment: string  
   }
   ```

I want operations to insert, view & update existing data.
Which document structure would be better for such a scenario and why?

Comment: It really depends on your usage. Much like with MongoDB of which NeDB is based on, arrays are good for cases where the "parent" and "child" interrelate. For example, incrementing a `commentCount` while using `$push` for each item is better for an array, rather than writing to what would be placed into two different namespaces otherwise. On the other hand if you needed to do something like "update all date values" then it's usually better to have separate entries.

Comment: Also to be clear. For "arrays" you really should have only "one", in this case. As in `{ machine: 1, data: [{ date: 1, comment: 'a' },{ date: 2, comment: 'b' }] }`. Otherwise keeping interrelated indices becomes too unwieldy.